# Select multiple files using DocumentPicker - iOS

Tags: ios, file-io

As per the [official guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/AccessingDocuments/AccessingDocuments.html), using `DocumentPicker`, currently I am able to select 1 file from the iOS device.
How can I select multiple files using the same? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3):

Selecting multiple files using `UIDocumentPickerViewController` can be done with [`allowsMultipleSelection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller/2902365-allowsmultipleselection) property, as shown below:

```swift
documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

Answer (score 0):

For that just set one counter,In which counter review the picker until you whant and  each save previous file path to "shared preferences" by using that you can select multiple files.

Comment: I will not know, how much files user wants to select and even if I ask the user to input it, I will have to launch the picker multiple times. That's not a good design practice.